# GCP Cloud build pass secret to docker arg

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I intend to pass my npm token to gcp cloud build,
so that I can use it in a multistage build, to install private npm packages.

I have the following abridged Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 AS build
ARG NPM_TOKEN

RUN echo "NPM_TOKEN:: ${NPM_TOKEN}"
```

and the following abridged cloudbuild.yaml:

```
---
  steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: [ '-c', 'gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=my-npm-token > npm-token.txt' ]
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
    - build
    - "-t"
    - gcr.io/my-project/my-program
    - "."
    - "--build-arg NPM_TOKEN= < npm-token.txt"
    - "--no-cache"
```

I based my cloudbuild.yaml on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials), but it seems like I am not able to put two and two together, as the expression: "--build-arg NPM_TOKEN= < npm-token.txt" does not work.
I have tested the DockerFile, when I directly pass in the npm token, and it works. I simply have trouble passing in a token from gcloud secrets as a build argument to docker.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your goal is to get the secret file contents into the build argument. Therefore you have to read the file content using either `NPM_TOKEN="$(cat npm-token.txt)"`or `NPM_TOKEN="$(< npm-token.txt)"`.

```yaml
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: [ '-c', 'docker build -t gcr.io/my-project/my-program . --build-arg NPM_TOKEN="$(cat npm-token.txt)" --no-cache' ]
```

Note: The gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker however use exec entrypoint form. Therefore you set entrypoint to bash.

Also note that you save the secret to the build [workspace](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#dir) (/workspace/..). This also allows you to copy the secret as a file into your container.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 AS build
ARG NPM_TOKEN

COPY npm-token.txt .
RUN echo "NPM_TOKEN:: $(cat npm-token.txt)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the end I simply uploaded my custom image to gcr. Cloud build is just an unnecessary abstraction, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I won't write your second step like you did, but like this:

```
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
    - "-c"
    - |
        build -t gcr.io/my-project/my-program . --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=$(cat npm-token.txt) --no-cache
```

Comment: The only syntax that worked for me! thanks a lot!