# cant get env variables in dockerfile

Tags: docker, yaml, gcloud, environment

I am trying to build my webapp in a gcloud run docker environment.
I want to build with staging environments and i was thinking i could use this part:

[image]

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
ARG configuration=${DOCKER_ENV}

RUN node ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --project=lunchtime --output-path=./dist/out --configuration $configuration --build-optimizer=false
FROM nginx:1.15
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/out/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build-stage /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

If i change $configuration to just staging or production it will work so the problem seems to be that DOCKER_ENV isn't defined.

I can see in my yaml file that the env is set there as i want it to.

[image]

Do I use the wrong syntax to be able to use the DOCKER_ENV in my docker file?

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62290603/4676641)? You may instead be wanting to use `args` if you want to access that variable at build time. [These docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#yaml_1) should show how.

Comment: hhmm i don't think i understand what he doing there :(

Comment: Sorry, I realized that post is only relevant to Cloud Build, not Cloud Run. The problem you're having seems to be not setting a build arg. You're setting environment variables for when the container is run but not when the container is built.

Comment: So I thought that: RUN node ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --project=lunchtime --output-path=./dist/out --configuration $configuration --build-optimizer=false 
Will build the app in the environment set in $configuration then the run argument will run whatevers is in the dict/out folder ? I mean this works when i hardcode $configuration to either staging/production

Comment: Correct, I understand that will work when `configuration` is hard coded. I was referring to when your Docker image itself is built. The problem is that `env` won't set the variable `DOCKER_ENV` when the `RUN` line is executed in your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable in Cloud Run are meant for your app at the runtime and not at the build time so when you define let's say a variable in Cloud Run like "FOO" you can access this variable from your Nodejs app using `process.env.FOO`.

To actually use environment variables in Dockerfile, you need to define them in the file or in GCB there is another way which is using Cloud Build. You can use it to define some variables which you can then use in different stages of the build like test, deploy ...etc:

```
steps:
# Uses the ubuntu build step:
# to run a shell script; and
# set env variables for its execution
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash', './myscript.sh']
  env:
  - 'BUILD=$BUILD_ID'
  - 'PROJECT=$PROJECT_ID'
  - 'REV=$REVISION_ID'

# Uses the docker build step to build an image called my-image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image', '.']

# my-image is pushed to Container Registry
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image'
```

read more about environemt variables in GCB [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values)